# Rails querying an associated models scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, scopes, associated-object

I am struggling to find a suitable solution for what should be a simple task. Essentially I have a **category model** which **has many** **posts**. The **post** belongs to the **category**.

I am displaying categories as part of a search form as well as a number of other places and do not want to display categories that have no associated posts. That seems kind of pointless.

I managed to solve this problem by adding the following method to my **category** model.

```
# Check if Category has associated results
def self.with_results
  includes(:posts).where.not(posts: { id: nil })
end
```

That works fine allowing me to filter categories that have no results. The slightly more confusing bit is when I try to use scopes.

My Post has several scopes such as `frontend_visible` which dictates whether it should be accessible from the frontend (non-admin).

```
scope :frontend_visible, -> { where(:state => ['approved', 'changes_pending_approval']) }
```

Equally I have other scopes to pull posts that are marked as private content only (members only).

The problem with my initial solution is that a category that contains posts which are not approved will not be shown, equally non-members will not be able to see posts that are marked as private although the category will still be shown.

The ideal solution would be something like:

Get all categories that have associated posts, if associated posts are not frontend visible, disregard category. If current_user can not access private content and all associated posts are marked private, disregard category.

I have the scopes but I am unsure how to use them from the associated model. Is this possible?

Comment: So you want all categories that have posts that are frontend visible?  Category.includes(:posts).where(frontend_visible: true).where.not(posts: {id: nil})  ... If you're on Rails5 you don't need to load the associated table if you're just querying to see if it has an associated record:    Category.where(frontend_visible: true).left_outer_joins(:posts).where(posts: { id: nil } )

Comment: [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes) you can find a solution ... e.g. merging-scope or scope-of-scope ...

Comment: @bkunzi01 Thank you, however neither of your examples work for me. I get the following error: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column categories.frontend_visible does not exist

Comment: @rfellons Thank you. I did take a look through that guide earlier. I guess what I am struggling with is using the scope as a condition within an associated model. I can not find a clear example of that kind of usage

Comment: Just spend some time learning active record.  This isn't a difficult concept so if you read the docs you can easily make whatever query you need.

Comment: I will have another look through. I had tried something similar to your example prior to posting this question which of course did not work. I am quite comfortable with scopes and AR in general but I have never had to access a scope as a condition from an associated model which I suppose was the point of my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i understand, you need to select categories with posts visible to an user. For that you need to do two things:

1. Make mapping between user’s roles and post’s visible scopes
2. Select categories for posts visible by user. In your case it’s easier to select that categories in two queries, without joins.

Try this code:

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :posts

  scope :with_posts_for_user, -> (user) do
    where(id: Post.categories_for_user(user))
  end
end

class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category

  scope :frontend_visible, -> { where(:state => ['approved', 'changes_pending_approval']) }
  scope :member_visible, -> { where(:state => ['approved', 'changes_pending_approval', 'private']) }

  scope :categories_for_user, -> (user) do
    (user.member? ? member_visible : frontend_visible).distinct.pluck(:category_id)
  end
end
```

Comment: Your solution is excellent, thank you for taking the time to share this!