# Active record query using associated model scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

model `Food` has many `Requests`

```rb
class Food < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :requests
  # scope :where_has_requests, -> { includes(:requests).where.not(requests: { id: nil }) }
end
```

`Requests` may belong to `User`

```rb
class Request < ActiveRecord::Base
  # belongs_to :giver, class_name: 'User'
  # belongs_to :receiver, class_name: 'User'
  scope :where_belongs_to, ->(user) { where(giver_id: user.id ).or(where(receiver_id: user.id)) }
end
```

How to query `Food` that has `Requests` which belongs to given `User` using Request scope?

```rb
Food.joins(:requests).where("requests.giver_id=#{user.id} OR requests.receiver_id=#{user.id}")
```

I've been thinking about this one:

```rb
Food.joins(:requests).where(requests.where_belongs_to(user))
```

But I'm lost. Any idea?

## Notice

I have seen [Rails querying an associated models scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43209400/rails-querying-an-associated-models-scope) **before** I've post this question, though I cannot understand it quite well and I think the cases are different somehow.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rails querying an associated models scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43209400/rails-querying-an-associated-models-scope)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need to do something like:

```
Food.joins(:requests).merge(Request.where_belongs_to(user))
```